# Subharmonic, Plurisubharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables

Can you give me **two** examples of [Subharmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function), [Plurisubharmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurisubharmonic)? (and **not** Subharmonic, **not** Plurisubharmonic) . Then prove that your examples.

I'm looking forward to your help. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried but I can't prove that :( . I want to have 2 examples which are easy to understand. Can you help me?

Comment: $\bullet $Ex: For $U$ is an open set in $E$, where $E$ is a complex Banach space and $f \in Holomorphic(U)$. Then $Re(f), Im(f), \left | f \right | \in PSH(U)$.
$\bullet $If $a+\overline{\Delta} b \subset U$. By Cauchy's integral formula, we have:
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(a+e^{it}b)\mathrm{d}t$$.
$\implies Ref(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}Ref(a+e^{it}b)\mathrm{d}t$
$$Im(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}Imf(a+e^{it}b)\mathrm{d}t$$
$$\left |f(a)  \right |=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left |f(a+e^{it}b)  \right |\mathrm{d}t$$. (But I want 2 easy example). :(

Comment: The easiest example of a subharmonic function on a domain $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is to take any holomorphic function $f\in\mathcal{O}(D)$ and consider $\log|f|$. So, for example, $\log|z|$ is subharmonic on $\mathbb{C}$. You can construct many examples of smooth non-subharmonic functions by using the fact that subharmonic functions have a maximum principle. So, for example, take a bump function.

Comment: Thanks Alex Youcis! What about $u$ is **not** a Subh, Plurisub? Can you give me 2 functions (easy)?

Comment: @kimtahe6 Did you see my last sentence? Since subharmonic, or more generally plurisubharmonic, functions have a maximum principle, a bump function cannot be PSH. For example, take the ball $B_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and consider the bump function $f$ on $B_1(0)$ which is $1$ at $0$, and slopes down to the boundary of $B_1(0)$. This can't be PSH since it's non-constant but obtains its max on $B_1(0)$.

Comment: In my textbook: "For $D$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. $\bullet$ If $u \in \mathcal{H}(D)$ then $\log|f|\in PSH(D)$. You mean, we choose $u=\log|z|$ is subharmonic in $\mathbb{c}$. That's Ok. And an other example? $\bullet$ You mean $B_1(0) =\Delta^n(0,1)=\{z\in \mathbb{C^n}:\|z\|=\max|z_i|<1 \}, v \in PSH(\mathbb{C^n})$, then $v|_{\partial\Delta^n(0,1)} \le u|_{\partial\Delta^n(0,1)}$. Hence, we don't have $v(z) \le u(z), \forall z \in \Delta^n(0,1) $. Do I have the correct understanding of your expression?

Comment: @kimtahe6 That's correct.

Comment: @kimtahe6: Can I ask, what class is this for? Is this a class in complex analysis or several complex variables or harmonic analysis or...? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 6):

A $C^2$-function $u$ is subharmonic if and only if the matrix (the complex Hessian)
$$ \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_j \partial \bar z_k} \right)$$
has positive trace. It is plurisubharmonic if and only if the complex Hessian is positive semidefinite.

To find some examples, try to construct a few functions whose complex Hessian is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
$$
to get examples of a plurisubharmonic, subharmonic (but not psh) and non-subharmonic function respectively.

Suitably interpreted, the same conditions are true for non-$C^2$ functions as well.

---

*Added later.* Details for the first example: If $$u(z_1,z_2) = |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = z_1\bar z_1 + z_2 \bar z_2,$$
then
$$ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z_1} = \bar z_1, \quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar z_1} = z_1, \quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z_2} = \bar z_2,  \quad\text{and}\quad 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar z_2} = z_2.
$$
Hence
$$ 
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z_1 \partial \bar z_1} = 1, \quad
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_1\partial \bar z_2} = 0, \quad
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_2\partial \bar z_1} = 0,
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_2 \partial \bar z_2} = 1.
$$
So this function works for the first example (plurisubharmonic and hence subharmonic). Make similar computations for the other examples.

Comment: I expect that I'll have a simple example, non-abstract with your prove (It will help me understand the problem). In particular, the function is non-subh/non-plurisubh/ . An other example? Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Any function that is not subharmonic is automatically not plurisubharmonic.

Comment: Yes, but i still don't find it, huhu :( .  Can you give me a few examples? **mrf** Thanks!

Comment: My suggestions above lead to $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$, $2|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2$ and $-|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2$ respectively. There are of course **lots** of other examples.

Comment: you mean that: $\bullet u(z_1,z_2)=\left|z_1\right|^2+\left|z_2\right|^2 \implies \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z_1}=2\left|z_1\right|\implies \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_2 \partial z_1}=2>0$. Hence, $u \in PSH(\Omega)$. $\bullet u(z_1,z_2)=- \left|z_1\right|^2-\left|z_2\right|^2 \implies \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_2 \partial z_1}=-2<0$. Hence, $u \not \in PSH(\Omega)$. Do I have the correct understanding of your expression?

Comment: @kimtahe6 Not quite, you've made several errors with the derivatives. See the above. (There are *four* second order derivatives that need to be computed.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I had had several errors! For $u=2\left | z_1 \right |^2-\left | z_2 \right |^2=2z_1\cdot\overline{z_1}-z_2\cdot\overline{z_2}$
$$\implies \dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_1 \cdot\partial \overline{z_1} }=2$$;
$$\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_2 \cdot\partial \overline{z_2} }=-1$$;$$\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_1 \cdot\partial \overline{z_2} }=0=\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_2 \cdot\partial \overline{z_1} }$$; Therefore, $\begin{pmatrix}
 & 2\,\,\,\,\,\,\ 0\\ 
 & 0\ -1
\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, $tr(H)=1>0$. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm sorry. I had had several errors! For $u(z_1,z_2)= - \left | z_1 \right |^2-\left | z_2 \right |^2=-z_1\cdot\overline{z_1}-z_2\cdot\overline{z_2}$
$$\implies \dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_1 \cdot\partial \overline{z_1} }=-1$$;
$$\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_2 \cdot\partial \overline{z_2} }=-1$$;$$\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_1 \cdot\partial \overline{z_2} }=0=\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z_2 \cdot\partial \overline{z_1} }$$; Therefore, $H_u(z)=\begin{pmatrix}
 & -1\,\,\,\,\,\,\ 0\\ 
 & 0\,\,\  -1
\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, $tr(H)=-2<0$. Is that correct?

Comment: @kimtahe6 That looks better

Comment: I thank for your guide. I'm very stupid :(, but with your explanation I can understand quickly. I learned from a very good person, maybe! That person is you.

Comment: Since your examples, I can try $u(z_1,z_2)=-2\left | z_1 \right |^2+\left | z_2 \right |^2 \implies H_u(z)=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad \implies$ u non-PSH. That's OK! Hihi

Comment: @ **mrf** : Can we use Laplace $\Delta u=\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1^2}+\ldots+\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x_n^2} \ge 0 \iff u \in SH(\Omega)$? Do you think so? It means The trace of the Hessian matrix of u?